# Mongolab MongoError: auth failed error

Tags: mongodb, mlab, geddy

I am using heroku for hosting my geddy app. The mongolab recently upgrade the version to mongo 3.x

I am using mongodb package 2.0.45 version which is latest. since the upgrade my app is throwing error of MongoError: auth failed error.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: try to move session storage from mongodb to memory
and update db.mongo key with , options : {
                authMechanism : 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
            }

Comment: Is there any documentation I can refer to for this?

Comment: https://github.com/geddy/geddy/wiki/sessions

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but just in case someone runs into this issue, I managed to solve this by upgrading my mongo shell to match the version in mongolab. I had 2.6 version of my mongo shell, but my mongolab db is in 3.0.6. This September, I believe Mongolab will again upgrade to 3.2 so you might need to upgrade again when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to upgrade your mongo gem version.
Try:
`bundle update mongo`

The version in my Gemfile.lock that solved is:

`gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.12.3'`
`gem 'mongo', '~> 1.12.3'`